# jQuery request image on focus

Tags: jquery

I would like to pull an image from the server when a user clicks into an input field (without preloading the image).

I have found the following code that shows text in a span when the input is in focus, but how would that need to be changed to request an image?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>span {display:none;}</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<p><input type="text" /> <span>focus fire</span></p>
<script>
  $("input").focus(function () {
    $(this).next("span").css('display','inline').fadeOut(1000);
  });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove span, and add div instead and then just update your method

```
  $("input").focus(function () {
    $(this).next("div").html('<img src="location to image" />');
  });
```